# Unable to start VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, windows-7

Probably due to lack of space of hard disk my Win7 Virtual Machine does not starts
(`Failed to start virtual machine`)

The `.vbox` file seems to be corrupted (not closed tags):
http://pastebin.com/j9NTqFgH

Here's the log file:
http://pastebin.com/gUSAd7g9

After closing the tags and creating new virtual machine with the old Win7 image Windows does not boots up.

How to fix this and restore the date I have on that machine?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your hard disk image is missing (or corrupted):

```
00:00:03.259 Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from Floppy 0 failed
00:00:03.259 Guest Log: BIOS: CDROM boot failure code : 0002
00:00:03.260 Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from CD-ROM failed
00:00:03.260 Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from Hard Disk 0 failed
00:00:03.260 Guest Log: BIOS: Booting from LAN...
00:00:03.583 Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from LAN failed
00:00:03.584 Guest Log: Could not read from the boot medium! System halted.
00:00:15.433 Changing the VM state from 'RUNNING' to 'SUSPENDING'.
```

Comment: Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Sorry, have no idea. According to the logs, VM does not have associated drive at all.

Comment: when I close the tags in .vbox file, the machine is trying to boot up, but it does not see the operating system.

Comment: Please elaborate what do you mean by *tags*.

Comment: the .vbox xml is not complete, some tags are not closed. I just close the missing ones, without adding any other options.

Comment: I see.. Well, seems like it's VB's issue then. But I see disk image there. I would try to purge all the configuration, keeping disk image, and then recreate VM with that image. If you already tried that - I'd suggest you to bring this question up on virtualbox forums or mailling list.